# Represent $1^5+2^4+3^3+4^2+5^1$ in sum notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I imagine the sum notation for

$$1^5+2^4+3^3+4^2+5^1$$

Would look something like

$$ \sum x^y,\ x=1 \text{ to } 5,\  y=5 \text{ to } 1 $$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that in each term, the sum of the base and the exponent is $6$.  Thus, if the base is $k$, the exponent is $6 - k$.  Since the base increases from $1$ to $5$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{5} k^{6 - k}$$

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I can think of:

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 k^{6-k}$$

$$\sum_{a,b\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge1}: a+b=6}a^b$$

Comment: Your second representation is a great way to generalize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{i=1}^5 i^{6-i}$ is equal to your sum

Answer (score 1):

One way in which it would often be done is
$$
\sum_{x=1}^5 x^{(1+5)-x}.
$$
If one were to write
$$
\sum_{(x,y)=(1,5)}^{(5,1)} x^y
$$
perhaps that would be understood, but I might write something after it like this:

> where $(x,y)$ runs through the set of integers points on a straight line connecting the two extremes

or the like.  With a suitable comment like that I would expect it to be understood.